# How to transfer data from first decoder to the second one?

Tags: java, netty

I have to decoders:

1. PingDecoder
2. HandshakeDecoder

in PingDecoder I read 1 byte, if it is PING byte, I just log it, if it is not I want to transfer all data (with this byte) to the HandshakeDecoder:

```
public class PingDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {
  ...
  @Override
  protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte prefix = in.readByte();
    if (prefix == PING) {
        log.debug("Ping");

    } else {
        out.add(prefix);
        out.add(in.readBytes(super.actualReadableBytes()));
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that HandshakeDecoder gets data without prefix.

Comment: What libraries are you using in the provided code? i.e what is ByteBuf, etc

Comment: @mrkachariker Netty 4.1.82.Final

Comment: Are you sure that the prefix in the case that its not equal to PING, is not equal to `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. I should send prefix as ByteBuf, not just byte:

```
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte prefix = in.readByte();
    if (prefix == PING) {
        log.debug("Ping");
    } else {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        buffer[0] = prefix;
        ByteBuf bb = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buffer);
        out.add(bb);
        if (in.isReadable()) {
            out.add(in.readBytes(super.actualReadableBytes()));
        }
    }
}
```